Jira Plugin Dev "ComponentAccessor has not been initialised"
When I execute my Jira Java plugin code, I receive the following error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: ComponentAccessor has not been initialised.
This is not expected to occur on a production system...

I've seen other posts with the same issue, but none of them resolve the problem. Any assistance is definitely appreciated!
Here is the code:
package com.atlassian.ccft.impl;

import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor;
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.MutableIssue;

public class mainCCFT {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String IssueReference = "CAP-3";
        String customFieldId = "CCFT Forecast Finish";
//      float UpdatedForecastFinish = (float) 41.6;
        
        // Instantiate the issue
//      ComponentAccessor issue = new ComponentAccessor();
        
        // Get the issue
        MutableIssue issue = ComponentAccessor.getIssueManager().getIssueByCurrentKey(IssueReference);
        
        // Get the custom field value
        Object forecastFinish = issue.getCustomFieldValue(ComponentAccessor.getCustomFieldManager().getCustomFieldObject(customFieldId));
        
        System.out.println(forecastFinish);
    }
}

The customField value should be printed out.
Other sites visited include:
ComponentAccessor not initialised
How do I get custom field values in jira?

Learn to use markdown to format your posts.

You are outside the Jira context and the code you provided is not even a Jira plugin.
An example old time plugin would look something like:
public class MyPlugin extends AbstractJiraContextProvider {

@Override
    public Map<String, Object> getContextMap(ApplicationUser applicationUser, JiraHelper jiraHelper) {
          CustomFieldManager customFieldManager = ComponentAccessor.getCustomFieldManager();
    ...

    }

 ...

}

Install the Atlassian SDK, read the docs and create the starter for your plugin with atlas-create. Once you have that, build via atlas-package and deploy to your installation. Then it will work. Alternatively, atlas-run will bootstrap a local Jira with your plugin in it - though I found this to be slow and error-prone.
